# Remove the Middle Name letter from firstName Column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a column with FirstName = JOYCE A 
I want to remove the "A" i.e, middle name & write the SQL command for it 
Result should be `FirstName = JOYCE`

Please help.

Comment: Careful, I bet not all use cases are this simple. What happens when they have more than 3 names? What about suffixes? Name normalization is very hard.

Comment: On the subject of name normalization... https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just display the updated first name, then try:

```
SELECT LEFT(FirstName, CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName + ' ') - 1) AS FirstName
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

If you actually want to update your table, then use:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET FirstName = LEFT(FirstName, CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName + ' ') - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming since the SSIS tag is on the question you're looking to do this in SSIS?  If so, add a C# Script Component to the Data Flow Task between the source and destination components with the following code.  The column that will be modified needs to be added as an available column with the `ReadWrite` usage type on the Input Columns page of the Script Component Editor.  This will go in the `Input0_ProcessInputRow` method, which executes once for each row is sent through it.

```
Row.FirstName= Row.FirstName.Substring(0, Row.FirstName.IndexOf(' '));
```